# Identify a Pod even after relaunch (Kubernetes)

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, containers, metrics, kubernetes-pod

I am currently monitoring Usage Metrics of Pods from Kubernetes (using Metricbeat) and storing it in DB for historical analysis.

If my Pod gets restarted the Pod name gets changed and will not be able to map the old Pod information with new Pod information.

Do we have any way to connect or identify the old and new information to form the final consolidated dataset?

Comment: use `deployment` with the image of `Metricbeat`??? Then you can refer the deployment via service and never have to bother about the name of pod ?

Comment: If you're using a Deployment, and update it to cause a redeploy, the new pods aren't directly related to the old ones in any particular way.  If you watch carefully during the update (`kubectl get pod -w`) both old and new pods will exist at the same time.  Dynamically scaling the deployment (maybe via the HorizontalPodAutoscaler) can also cause apparent discontinuities as pods appear and vanish.